# can I find the area of parallelogram using cross product?

Tags: vectors

> $\vec u = 1,1,-1$ and $\vec v = 1,1,1$
>
> So, $\vec p$ is projection vector $\vec u$ into $\vec v$ and $\vec q$ is the projection vector $\vec v$ into $\vec u$
>
> $\cos \theta = 1/3$

I have tried but the answer i got is $\frac 92$ the right answer is $\frac 92 \sqrt 2$

How to do cross product to find the area of parallelogram?

Cross product like this https://www.analyzemath.com/stepbystep_mathworksheets/vectors/cross_product.html

Comment: What is $\theta$ and how can $\vec u\cos\theta$ be a number?

Comment: Oh. I corrected it

Comment: you want to find the area of the parallelogram formed by $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ ?

Comment: Yes. Using cross product

Comment: Magnitude of cross product is product of magnitudes of vectors and $\sin\theta$